# Why OpenFileDialog RestoreDirectory not implemented?

Tags: wpf, openfiledialog

I'm using Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog in my wpf application since it is stated as equivalent here; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750559.aspx

I set the RestoreDirectory property to true, but it has no effect.
When I wait on the property it is documented that "This property is not implemented."

So how can I achieve this task without implementing the logic myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RestoreDirectory is automaticly implemented.

```
string fileName = string.Empty;

var dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
dialog.InitialDirectory = @"c:\test";
if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    fileName = dialog.FileName;
```

if you don't specify InitialDirectory it will open last selected file's directory

Comment: No, it's not implemented in WPF version.  RestoreDirectory is supposed to restore the last folder, after the dialog is closed.  It doesn't.